# capturar valor de un input y multiplicarlo por un valor de mi base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola buenas tardes amigos estoy un poco atorado con algo que estoy tratando de hacer...

estoy haciendo una tabla donde traigo mis valores de la base de datos por medio de jquery ajax

y en un campo de la tabla estoy poniendo un input text para que ingresen un numero y multiplicarlo por un valor de la base de datos y en otro campo de la tabla aparezca el resultado de la multiplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/function/funciones.php',
  method:'post',
  data: {
    escanFrus: codigoNumber.escanFrus.value,
  },
})
.done(function(datos) {
  console.log( datos );
  if (datos === false) {
    alert('No se encontro el Frus escaneado');
    return;
  }
  $('#tablaFrus').append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>').append( datos.part_number ))
    .append($('<td>').append( datos.fru_weiIght ))
    .append($('<td>').append('<input type="text" id="piezas" name="piezas" class="inputable">'))
    .append($('<td>').append('<label id="pesoMultiple"></label>'))
  );
})
```

creo que asi es como puedo obtener el valor del input

```
let pzas = document.getElementById('piezas').value = "";
```

pero como puedo hacerle para poder multiplicarlo por el valor de mi base de datos y luego ponerlo en el campo ?? alguna idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar un atributo en el input al momento de agregarlo en la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
append($('<td>').append('<input type="text" id="piezas" name="piezas" class="inputable" data-valor-base="' + datos.multiplicador + '"'>
```

Y con javascript puedes obtener el valor de ese atributo

```
var multiplicador = document.getElementById('piezas').getAttribute("data-valor-base")
```

La variable multiplicador tomará el valor 5. Entonces podrás hacer tu operación y colocar el resultado en donde vaya.

La imagen me aclaró un poco, yo lo haría así:
HTML:

```
<table id="tablaFrus">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Peso</th>
        <th>Piezas</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
var arr = [
 { part_number:1, fru_weiIght  : 1.82 },
 { part_number:2, fru_weiIght  : 2.82 },
 { part_number:3, fru_weiIght  : 4.82 },
 { part_number:4, fru_weiIght  : 3.82 },
]

arr.forEach(function(item, index){
  var str = "<tr>";
  str += "<td>" + item.fru_weiIght +"</td>"
  str += "<td><input class='inputable' data-part_number='" +  item.part_number +"' data-fru_weiIght='" + item.fru_weiIght + "'/></td>"
  str += "<td><label data-part_number='" + item.part_number +"'>Resultado</label></td>"
  str += "</tr>"
  $("#tablaFrus").find("tbody").append(str)
})

$( ".inputable" ).on( "change", function() {
   var peso = $(this).attr("data-fru_weiIght");
   var part = $(this).attr("data-part_number");
   var resultado = $(this).val() * peso;
   $("label[data-part_number = '" + part +"']").text(resultado)
});
```

Adjunto código en gists: https://gist.github.com/Lvcios/477ebcb80cc2c7be5ab630caad55e862

Comment: este campo data-valor-base=" " lo deje vació ya que si le asigno un valor siempre me tomara el 5 por defecto y no es lo que ocupo ademas que me marca erro al mandar llamar getAttribute

Comment: En donde puse el 5 se supone debes poner el valor que traes de la base de datos. Solo lo puse como ejemplo pero voy a modificar el post.

Comment: la vdd no entiendo mucho y creo que tu ami tampoco, modifique el post para que cheques el ejemplo y veas lo que intento hacer, por que al traer el dato y ponerlo en el imput no me ayuda mucho al momento de hacer la multiplicacion

Comment: Ya con la imagen me quedó mas claro lo que quieres lograr, he editado mi respuesta.

Comment: excelente muchisimas gracias justamente eso es lo que quería hacer, gracias por tu tiempo y explicacion

Comment: ahora tengo un problema estoy intentando hacer la suma de esa columna por medio de un for each pero para obetener el valor lo tomo de la variable resultado y lo intento sumar pero no logro el resultado como podri hacerlo??

Comment: Con jquery puedes obtener la lista de los elementos con el mismo nombre. Sería algo así como 

$("#tablaFrus").find("label[name='nombre_label']")

Con eso puedes hacer un foreach y obtener el texto que está dentro del label y convertirlo a número y sumarlo.

Comment: si de echo asi es como lo estoy haciendo pero solo me muestra el valor nuevo no me va sumando los valores.var sumafruz = 0;
        $("#tablaFrus").find("label[name='sumaColumna']").each(function(){
          sumafruz +=parseFloat($(this).html())|| 0;
        })
        console.log(sumafruz);
        $('#totalFrus').text(sumafruz);
      });

Comment: listo ya lo solucione muchas gracias